# Is it possible to share secrets among ECS Container Definitions in Cloud-formation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have requirement to create 5 Container definitions which have common environmental variables as secrets. But the count of them is around 50. So instead of duplicating these 50 secrets, is there a way I can create all these a single resource and refer them in all container definitions ?

Comment: Whether its single resource or not, you still need to referrer to it 50 times. The only way I see to avoid any kind repetition is to create CloudFormation macro which would process and expand the template for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store. It's intended for this kind of situation, when sharing config values between multiple containers, lambda functions, etc.

Comment: no the point is, even-though I use system SSM or secret manager, I have to enter the key and for value I refer from SSM. But if I do this entry 50 times, for 5 container definition, it increases size of my CloudFormation and duplication of keys

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is not out of the box way for this more advanced use case. I would take a look at something like Hashicorp Vault

Comment: Alternative is to use YAML variables or something like that to deduplicate